# How to write into session with web api?

Tags: xcode, session, asp.net-web-api

I am writing an authentication code. I am authenticating against the web server. currently my code take the username and password from xcode and send it over to the web service via the URL which then returns a json string that I am reading in xcode. When the connection is succefull I want to create a session and in xcode i want to read that session.

Web Api:

```
public class SessionController : ApiController
{
    public bool loggedin = false;

    public class MyHttpControllerHandler: HttpControllerHandler, IRequiresSessionState
    {
        public MyHttpControllerHandler(RouteData routeData): base(routeData)
        { }
    }
    public class MyHttpControllerRouteHandler : HttpControllerRouteHandler
    {
        protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(
            RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            return new MyHttpControllerHandler(requestContext.RouteData);
        }
    }
    public void Authenticate(string txtLoginId, string txtPassword)
    {
        Subs objSub = SubService.GetSubs(txtLoginId.Trim(), txtPassword.Trim());

        if (objSub != null)
        {
            loggedin = true;
        }
        else
            loggedin = false;
    }
    public string Get(string user, string pass)
    {

        byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(pass);
        string password = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

        Authenticate(user, password);

        if(loggedin == true)
        {
            var session = HttpContext.Current.Session;
            session["Time"] = DateTime.Now;
            return "Session Time: " + session["Time"] + user;
        }else
            return "Session is not availabe " + user;
    }         
}
```

it returns the following error on this line,

```
session["Time"] = DateTime.Now;

ExceptionMessage":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your intention here; do you want to tell the server to end the session after 20 mins or do you just want to check session status?

Comment: I want to check the status. I modified the last sentence above.

Comment: I don't see anything in the API code you have posted to return the session status. Does the API have this functionality?

Comment: Can you look at the code now? I shrank it and display only the important staff.

Comment: I don't think that error is related to session status. Perhaps an initialisation issue?